# CodeIgniter - validation rules in custom config file

Tags: php, validation, codeigniter

On the CodeIgniter User Guide I've read that we can save validation rules into an array in application/config/form_validation.php

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#savingtoconfig

I'm wondering if is possible to save these rules into a different config files like application/config/my_library.php

Form_validation.php should be like that:

```
<?php $config = array(
             'signup' => array(
                                array(
                                        'field' => 'username',
                                        'label' => 'Username',
                                        'rules' => 'required'
                                     ),
                                array(
                                        'field' => 'password',
                                        'label' => 'Password',
                                        'rules' => 'required'
                                     ),
                                array(
                                        'field' => 'passconf',
                                        'label' => 'PasswordConfirmation',
                                        'rules' => 'required'
                                     ),
                                array(
                                        'field' => 'email',
                                        'label' => 'Email',
                                        'rules' => 'required'
                                     )
                                ),
             'email' => array(
                                array(
                                        'field' => 'emailaddress',
                                        'label' => 'EmailAddress',
                                        'rules' => 'required|valid_email'
                                     ),
                                array(
                                        'field' => 'name',
                                        'label' => 'Name',
                                        'rules' => 'required|alpha'
                                     ),
                                array(
                                        'field' => 'title',
                                        'label' => 'Title',
                                        'rules' => 'required'
                                     ),
                                array(
                                        'field' => 'message',
                                        'label' => 'MessageBody',
                                        'rules' => 'required'
                                     )
                                )                          
           );
```

where each sub-array like 'email' or 'signup' identify a different form

Answer (score 0):

It has to be a single file but you can split the rules into sets, as explained in the link you referenced, under "Creating Sets of Rules"

Comment: I know, so i can't use more than one file?